# View & Read STDERR for for debugging

Tags: 14.04, log

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-88-generic x86_64) server.

I ran below code to get my GUI set up:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I need to read the stderr to find issue I'm running and debug further.

I'm new to Ubuntu system. How and where can find & read stderr file for further debugging.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: These file are found in the `/var/log` directory, look in there!

Comment: thanks, @George I did `cd /var/log` I see a bunch of files or directories but no STDERR. Appreciate if you could help me further

Comment: In there you find files with output stuffs from different processes so what you call stderr will be found in one of those files depending on which process generated that error, and you can create custom error logs in there too

Comment: `stderr` is a *stream* - unless you explicitly redirect it to a file, it is normally output to the terminal in which you run a command. What exactly do you think you are missing?

Comment: If your debugging a process you created then you need to use the Ubuntu `redirect` to pass the errors to any file and location of your liking

Comment: As mentioned I'm using ubuntu server so my web application is sending the error. The error I'm looking for is `LAUNCHY_DEBUG `. How can I `redirect` these types of errors to that file?

Comment: @FriendofAfriend that's not related to whether you are using a GUI or a server version - it will be a matter of how the application is designed / configured to log its errors and how it is started (as a service versus a foreground application)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug some command using its error messages you should do the following `command 2>debug.txt` - thus all information from **STDERR** stream about errors will be saved in file named **debug.txt**.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. Im new to ubuntu, sorry for not understanding completely. As mentioned I'm using ubuntu server so my web application is sending the error. The error I'm looking for is `LAUNCHY_DEBUG `. how would I need to do it with `command 2>debug.txt` and from where? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Is it a PHP application or something else?

Comment: Its a Ruby application

Comment: I have no experience using Ruby but you can try to follow this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts. I hope, it will help you.

Comment: For the error, you don't need to know Ruby, I've already set everything up. Only thing I need to know is how and where to view my log. appreciate your time